# UUID random number in xquery using java

Tags: xquery

I don't know why but I got `()` when I'm trying to use:

```
declare namespace uuid='java.util.UUID';

uuid:randomUUID
```

in XQuery

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single answer on your question, because the exact behavior depends on the XQuery processor.

---

With **BaseX**, you should get the expected result if you invoke `uuid:randomUUID` as function:

```
declare namespace uuid = 'java.util.UUID';
uuid:randomUUID()
```

But it’s recommendable to call [`random:uuid()`](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Random_Module) instead. No namespace needs to be imported, and evaluation will be faster than with Java function calls.

---

With **Saxon** and (as far as I know) **eXist-db**, you will need to prefix the namespace URI string with `java:`. This also works with BaseX:

```
declare namespace uuid = 'java:java.util.UUID';
uuid:randomUUID()
```

---

With **MarkLogic,** you can use the [`sem:uuid-string()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/sem:uuid-string) function.